# Arangodb update properties depend on edge type

Tags: database, arangodb, aql

I am trying to use AQL to update the whole node collection , named **Nodes**, depend on the type of edges they have
.

Requirement:

- Basically, if 2 entity in **Nodes** has relation type= "Same", they would be updated with unique **groupid** properties (same for more than 2)
- This would only run one time in the beginning (to populate **groupid**)

My concept approach:

- Use AQL
- For each entity inside **Node**, query out all connectable nodes with type=**SAME**
- Generate an groupid and Update all of them
- Write to an lookup object those id
- For next entity, do a lookup, skip the entity if their id is there.

What I tried

```
FOR v,e,p
In 1..10
ANY v
EntityRelationTest
OPTIONS {uniqueVertices:"global",bfs:true}
FILTER p.edges[*].relationType[0]== "EQUALS"
UPDATE v WITH { typeName2:"test1"} IN EntityTest 
return NEW
```

But I am quite new to arangodb AQL, is something like above possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, what I use is a customize traversal object running directly inside Foxx in order to get the best of both world: performance and correctness. It seemed that we cannot do the above with only AQL